# Does anyone know how to make images follow device movements like this, on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QVCV.png

Does anyone know how to make images follow device movements like this, on Flutter?

so I can't post pictures because my reputation is still lacking :(

Comment: https://abhimortal6.medium.com/flutter-smooth-parallax-effect-for-login-and-intro-screens-10bf42073741

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can use `sensors_plus` packages to get moment of the phone.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fq5zNPJufD0

or `flutter_sensors` or `motion_sensors`

After that you can use any solution to rotate your image, example use `RotatedBox` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html

Good luck.